# Segment Fault - Linked List in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

I am creating a basic linked list in C but I am getting a segment fault when my add to back function is called in my test file. It seems to have a problem because the head of the list is NULL, but I don't see why this is an issue. When I use the cgdb tool, it tells me the error is occurring on the line: prev->next = new_node. I have attached the full code below, please let me know what I am not seeing to fix this.

header file

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *create_node(int data);
void free_list(Node *head);
void add_to_front(struct Node **head, int data);
void print_list(struct Node *head);
void reverse_list(struct Node **head);
void add_to_back(Node **head, int data);

#endif // LINKED_LIST_H
```

.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

/* returns a new node whose data is set to DATA and next is set to NULL */
Node *create_node(int data) {
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        perror("Malloc failed\n");
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}


/* Frees the list starting at HEAD */
void free_list(Node *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        Node *temp = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = temp;
    }
}

/* Creates a new node whose data is set to DATA and adds it to the front of the
   list pointed to by HEAD.
   */
void add_to_front(struct Node **head, int data) {
    /* Check if the head is NULL to make sure that we do not dereference a NULL pointer
    because that would result in a segfault */
    if (head == NULL) return;
    struct Node *new_node = create_node(data);
    if (*head != NULL) {
        /* The list is not empty */
        /* The new node's next should point to the head */
        new_node->next = *head;
    }
    /* We must set HEAD using the following line in order to change the original list */
    *head = new_node;
    /* The following line would not work because it would only change our local copy of HEAD */
    /* head = new_node */
}

/* Prints out a linked list starting at HEAD */
void print_list(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *curr;
    for (curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        printf("%d->", curr->data);
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

/* Iteratively reverses a linked list whose first node is HEAD */
void reverse_list(struct Node **head) {
    if (head == NULL || *head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    struct Node *curr = *head;
    struct Node *next = (*head)->next;
    curr->next = NULL;
    while (next != NULL) {
        struct Node *temp = next->next;
        next->next = curr;
        curr = next;
        next = temp;
    }
    *head = curr;
}

/* Creates a new node with a data field set to DATA and adds the node
   to the back of the list pointed to by HEAD */
void add_to_back(Node **head, int data) {
    if (head == NULL || *head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    Node *new_node = create_node(data);
    Node *prev;
    for (Node *curr = *head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
        prev = curr;
    }
    prev->next = new_node;
}
```

test file

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Running tests...\n\n");

    Node *head = NULL;

    /*********** reverse_list test ***********/
    reverse_list(&head);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        add_to_front(&head, i);
        reverse_list(&head);
    }

    int expected_values[] = {3, 1, 0, 2, 4};
    Node *curr = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        assert(curr->data == expected_values[i]);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    free_list(head);

    printf("Congrats! You have passed the reverse_list test!\n\n");

    /************ add_to_back test ***********/
    Node *head_2 = NULL;
    add_to_back(&head_2, 15);
    add_to_back(&head_2, 12);
    add_to_back(&head_2, 18);
    int expected_values_2[] = {15, 12, 18};
    Node *curr_2 = head_2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        assert(curr_2->data == expected_values_2[i]);
        curr_2 = curr_2->next;
    }
    free_list(head_2);

    printf("Congrats! All of the test cases passed!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `add_to_back()` on an *empty* list? What will `prev` point to?

Comment: @John Goldstein This if statement if (head == NULL || *head == NULL) {
        return;
    } does not make a sense. You can not append a node to an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement in the function `add_to_back`

```
if (head == NULL || *head == NULL) {
    return;
}
```

does not make a sense because it does not allow to append a node to an empty list.

The function can be defined for example like

```
void add_to_back( Node **head, int data ) 
{
    if ( head == NULL ) return;

    Node *new_node = create_node(data);

    while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

    *head = new_node;
}
```

Or using your approach then

```
void add_to_back( Node **head, int data ) 
{
    if ( head == NULL ) return;

    Node *new_node = create_node(data);

    Node *prev = NULL;

    for ( Node *curr = *head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next ) 
    {
        prev = curr;
    }

    prev == NULL ? ( *head = new_node ) : ( prev->next = new_node );
}
```

In general this statement

```
if ( head == NULL ) return;
```

is also redundant. If the user will pass a null pointer then the function just will have undefined behavior.

On the other hand the function `create_node` should be written the following way

```
Node * create_node( int data ) 
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;
    }

    return new_node;
}
```

Correspondingly for example the function `add_to_back` can be written like

```
int add_to_back( Node **head, int data ) 
{
    Node *new_node = create_node( data );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        Node *prev = NULL;

        for ( Node *curr = *head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next ) 
        {
            prev = curr;
        }

        prev == NULL ? ( *head = new_node ) : ( prev->next = new_node );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the add_to_back() function. Because of first line in that function  `if (head == NULL || *head == NULL) { return; }`, it will keep returning and not executing rest of the code. So, if you print your list after three calls of the add_to_back function, your list has nothing but NULL and that is the reason you are getting a segmentation fault. I did the following change and your code is working fine
`
void add_to_back(Node **head, int data) {

```
Node *new_node = create_node(data);
if (*head == NULL){
    *head =  new_node;
    return;
}
Node *prev;
for (Node *curr = *head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
    prev = curr;
}
prev->next = new_node;
```

}
`